# Secure property placeholder throwing an error on MMC while deployment

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio, mule-esb

I am trying to deploy project which has implemented secure property placeholder on the On-Prem MMC but its throwing error while deployment saying

"org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'Secure_Property_Placeholder': Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; nested PropertyAccessException"

But when I deploy it on Anypoint Studio or on CloudHub it gets deployed.

Need help on in the emergency.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added encryption password in the server? If not, please add it in wrapper.conf file.